# How to approach non-latin characters in ElasticSearch autocompletion with Mongoosastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoosastic

Autocompletion is working fine using `es.search({size: 0, suggest: ...}` using completion mapping on a field that can have non-latin diacritics (accented characters like â, ê, etc.).

I am creating mappings using `mongoosastic`. I need to be able to use something like `asciifolding` for suggestions or add additional field to the response.

I have those fields:

- `name` which is the one with diacritics.
- `nameSearch` which is the `name` latinized (no diacritics/accented characters).

What I need is to either continue completion suggestions over `name` but treat `a` the same as `â` (and the other way).

In the response I need `name`. Not `nameSearch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled on this problem again, this time without `mongoosastic`. The answer is to have `settings` field in the index query (in `mongoosastic` you can add it when using custom mappings).

```
settings: {
  analysis: {
    analyzer: {
      folding: {
        tokenizer: 'standard',
        filter: ['lowercase', 'custom_asciifolding'],
      },
    },
    filter: {
      custom_asciifolding: {
        type: 'asciifolding',
        preserve_original: true,
      },
    },
  },
}
```